# How can you change the "view" of a Javascript object/function for debugger purposes in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Is it possible to change how google chrome views the collapsed form of objects for debugging? I've heard reference to creating functions called toString but I was unable to get them to work, so assumed that those questions were somewhat dated.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1FTascZXT9cxfetuPRT2eXPQKXui4nWFivUnS_335T3U/preview

Comment: Thanks, copy a quote from there, with the link and you will get rep for accepted answer